# Tabela na vertical template Flask

Tags: html, python, front-end, flask

Sou iniciante no flask e no Front-end tenho uma tabela que ela me retorna informação de uma API, só que em vez de ela jogar informação na tabela na vertical ela está indo para horizontal, como eu faço para corrigir isso?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Minha pagina</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Teste de API</h1>
    <br>

    <table border = "1">
        <tr>
            <td align= middle width=100 bgcolor= #DAA520> ID </td>
            <td align= middle width=100 bgcolor= #DAA520> TITLE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        {% for i in range(4) %}
            <td align= middle width=150>{{data[i] ["id"]}}</td>
            <td align= middle width=150>{{data[i]["title"]}}</td>

        {% endfor %}

        </tr>

    </table>

</body>


</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for i in range(4) %}
<tr>
        <td align= middle width=150>{{data[i] ["id"]}}</td>
        <td align= middle width=150>{{data[i]["title"]}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```